# Pixelated and blurry playback of video stream

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, getusermedia, mediastream

I have this code that plays video from stream:

```
let player = document.querySelector("#player");
player.srcObject = videoStream;
```

The problem, the playback is very pixelated and blurry:

[image]

How can I debug and find the root issue that cause the blurry playback?

Comment: OBS Virtual Web Camera

Comment: Using `getUserMedia`

Comment: Does this happens with all browsers? Is the quality better when you use an other software to render this stream?

Comment: Yes when I use the online web cam tester the video is crisp and clear.

Comment: What about other browsers? You can try to see what Chrome detects in `chrome://media-internals` -> "Video Capture"

Comment: I can see "OBS-Camera" with 1920x1080 30.00